# having problem using form.controls.errors.(myError) (error is from AbstractControl) in ngClass in angular

Tags: angular, forms, angular-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have created an validation (in ReactiveForm) using abstractControl and wanted to use it in ngClass.

here is my code:

```
inputForm = new FormGroup({
   current_password: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required
   ]),
   new_password: new FormControl('', [
     Validators.required
   ]),
   re_new_password: new FormControl('', [
     Validators.required
   ])
  }, [
   (form: AbstractControl) => {
     if (form.value.new_pass === form.value.re_new_pass) {
       return null;
     }
     return { equation: true }
   }
 ])
```

html:

```
<form [formGroup]="inputForm">
   <div>
      <label>Current Password : </label>
      <input class="form-input" formControlName="current_password">
   </div>
   <div>
      <label>Password : </label>
      <input class="input-form" formControlName="new_password" [ngClass]="{ 'red-border': inputForm.errors.equation }">
   </div>
   <div>
      <label>Password Confirmation : </label>
      <input class="input-form" formControlName="re_new_password" [ngClass]="{ 'red-border': inputForm.errors.equation }">
   </div>
</form>
```

when this form get valid equation error will get null and
that's where I have problem with ngClass
because no error called 'equation'

how should i solve this ?

Comment: What if you replace `return null` with `return { equation: false }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your .ts file like below

```
  inputForm = new FormGroup({
    current_password: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required
    ]),
    new_password: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required
    ]),
    re_new_password: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required
    ])
  }, [
    (form: FormGroup) => {
      if (form.controls.new_password.value === form.controls.re_new_password.value) {
        return null;
      }
      return {equation: true}
    }
  ])
```

and your template must be like this

```
  <form [formGroup]="inputForm">
    <div>
      <label>Current Password : </label>
      <input class="form-input" formControlName="current_password">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Password : </label>
      <input class="input-form" formControlName="new_password"
             [ngClass]="{ 'red-border': inputForm.errors?.equation}">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Password Confirmation : </label>
      <input class="input-form" formControlName="re_new_password"
             [ngClass]="{ 'red-border': inputForm.errors?.equation}">
    </div>
  </form>
```

Pay attention to question mark. it makes sure you won't see null and undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You need [`?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) optional chaining to escape the possibly null error.

As [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)'s error is with `ValidationErrors` or `null` type.

```
errors: ValidationErrors | null
```

```
<input
  class="input-form"
  formControlName="new_password"
  [ngClass]="{ 'red-border': inputForm.errors?.equation }"
/>

<input
  class="input-form"
  formControlName="re_new_password"
  [ngClass]="{ 'red-border': inputForm.errors?.equation }"
/>
```

And also correct the statement as `new_pass` and `re_new_pass` doesn't exist as the `FormControl` (typo error) as below:

```js
if (form.value.new_password === form.value.re_new_password)
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vsv3np?file=src/app/app.component.html)